# Make my own function require in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, module, require

Let me know how it works internally require () function in javascript.

I want to make something like this: `define(["./path"], function(cart, inventory) { });`,
but every time I look for it on Google, the results are only frameworks or tutorials for use it, but I wonder how it works inside this function, make it just to understand it better.

Does anyone know of a tutorial that explains how to do this function manually?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not read source code of any of those frameworks?

Comment: It's hard to understand!

Answer (score 0):

require function it's just a part of [commonjs](http://www.commonjs.org/) standart. This standart has a number of implementations for working in browser ([requirejs](http://requirejs.org/), [stitch](https://github.com/sstephenson/stitch)).

Comment: RequireJS has nothing to do with CommonJS require (as we know it from Node.js), this name is very misleading, it's very different "require"

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake and JavaScript Modules slides: http://www.slideshare.net/medikoo/javascript-modules-done-right It's all explained there.

"define" is AMD require, which is totally different beast from CommonJS/NodeJS require, I would suggest to just stick to CommonJS/Node.js style, it's simpler, more powerful and your code would be cleaner.